# Getting error file_get_contents failed to open stream when trying to make an API post request without cURL

Tags: php, laravel, curl, post

Please I need your help. I need to make a post request using file get contents and I am getting this error

**file_get_contents(https://api.paystack.co/transferrecipient): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

Here's the company's cURL requirement:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
   "type": "nuban",
   "name": "Account 1029",
   "description": "Customer1029 bank account",
   "account_number": "01000000010",
   "bank_code": "044",
   "currency": "NGN",
 }' "https://api.paystack,co/transferrecipient
```

**AND MY CODE**

```
                //create the content to post to get recipient code
                $content = json_encode([
                            'type' => 'nuban',
                            'name' => $request->username,
                            'description' =>  $request->username.' bank account',
                            'account_number' => $request->acc_number,
                            'bank_code' => $request->bank,
                            'currency' => 'NGN'  
                        ]);

                $opt = [
                    "http" => [
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer secret_key',
                        $content        
                    ]
                ];

                $con = stream_context_create($opt);

                $datas = file_get_contents('https://api.paystack.co/transferrecipient', false, $con);

                return $datas = json_decode($datas, true);
```

Comment: 400 = page does not exist

Comment: 400 = Bad Request, you prepare a wrong request -- 
404 = page does not exist

Comment: I'd suggest using curl instead of file_get_contents. It's a lot easier to work with, and `file_get_contents` doesn't allow url access on some servers.

Comment: The page exists. I agree that my request is bad. That’s what I am trying to figure out. Please my main issue is how to pass the data -d with my own code instead of curl. I believe if I get that everything will be fine

Comment: You can't have two of the same keys in an array, it will clash. Only one of your header keys are being passed in. See [here on how to properly send more than one header line](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#refsect1-function.stream-context-create-examples)

Comment: Opps, thanks @aynber let me get rid of it and retry

Answer (score 1):

You have two `header` keys and no `content` key for your json payload. You should be able to change the `header` to an array and set the `content` key as follows:

```
$opt = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer secret_key"
        ),
        'content' => $content
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks @cOle2 it worked. Upvoted you but since my reputation is less that 15 for now, it’s not displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be easier with php-curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.paystack.co/transferrecipient");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'method' => 'POST',
     'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
     'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer secret_key'));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks @efenacigiray. I’ll start giving more attention to cURL. Upvoted your answer too.